# Batch file incorrectly sets the root directory of Python script

Tags: python, batch-file, filepath, gdal, osgeo

**Problem**

I have a gdal2tiles.bat file that says

```
@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py" %*
```

However, when I run the script from Powershell as `gdal2tiles earth.tif` or `gdal2tiles.bat earth.tif`, the error message says

> The system cannot find the path specified. python: can't open file
> 'C:\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory

**Workaround**

I edit the .bat file to put the file path of the .py file like the code below. I run it and it says `The system cannot find the path specified.` then the script runs as intended with correct output.

```
@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
python "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2tiles.py" %*
```

However, the gdal2tiles.py is just one of the many Python scripts in the folder. If I need to run a different script, I need to edit its .bat file again.

[image: Batch files in folder]

My previous post is similar to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/414053/146811

**What's a good fix that doesn't need me to edit all the .bat files?**

Comment: Nevermind, please see this thread for a better workaround https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414089/146811

Comment: If it works without using the variable `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%`, and that variable worked to launch `"%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"`, then clearly the issue is that something in `o4w_env.bat` is undefining that variable. In order to identify the issue, we would need to see the content of `o4w_env.bat`. Please do not crosspost your questions, if you have decided that the poor advice you're receiving over there is satisfactory, then please delete your question here.

Comment: Where/how do you set the variable `OSGEO4W_ROOT`?

Comment: @aschipfl Edit the system variables > Environment Variables... > make new System Variable

Comment: And what is its value? type `set OSGEO4W_ROOT` into a Command Prompt window to verify…

Comment: It's `C:\OSGeo4W`

Comment: Perhaps you need to put `cd /D "%~dp0."` as the second line of the batch script, so an argument like `earth.tif` is searched in the parent directory of the batch script (which is what I assume)…